# Fail to integrate CKeditor in rails_admin gem (use gem rich)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I follow the link [GitHub gem rich](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich#readme) to install CKeditor to rails_admin
but I get the error: `Unsupported field datatype: rich_editor`

My model

```
edit do
        field :title
        field :description, :rich_editor do
          config({
            :insert_many => true
          })
        end
        field :autho
        field :book_type
      end
```

How can I fix this error? Or that's an issue?

---

**EDIT**:
I tried it, and it worked

```
field :content, :text do
      ckeditor do true end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. I think it is an issue in rails_admin or in rich. I have successfully integrate these two together in past (but with old versions of both).

I have created github issues for this in rich (https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich/issues/80) and rails_admin (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1585) repos.

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, and it contains the solution, hope it'll help you!

Comment: Thanks! But this will just add support for the ckeditor, but not for rich?

Comment: I don't know how to use rick_editor in rails_admin, but actually, the rich_editor build on ckeditor base. So feel free to use it!https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the Rich gem to work with a Rails 4 project using Rails admin, so I decided to use the standard CK Editor Gem which is the recommended course of action by the authors. It took all of 5 minutes to get it working following this:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CKEditor

Then I configured my CK_Editor to use a small subset of the available functionality.

After adding the CK_Editor gem and configuring my rails admin initializer, I created a new javascript file in my project at:

/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

with the following contents:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ],
    items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ],
    items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote',
         'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
```

];

Remember to restart your Rails server!